# CSS float items with borders - But not on each side

Tags: css, grid, css-float, border, gallery

**Question**

I have a simple floated list with borders on each item, but not on each side.

- The grid I'm trying to create looks very much like this character #
- Full borders on each item on the inside, no containing border surrounding it, no outline.

How?

**The example**

- In the example there are bottom borders to the last items. They should not be there.
- In the example there are right borders on the edge to the right. They should not be there.
- The first and the third item are correct in the first list.
- The first and the second items are correct in the second list.

**Fiddle**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0bLa6ve/4/) (Updated with expected result)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>

<br><br>

<ul class="three">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>

<h2>Expected result</h2>

<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li style="border-right: none;">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
     <li style="border-right: none;">Four</li>
    <li style="border-bottom: none;">Five</li>
</ul>

<br><br>

<ul class="three">
  <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li style="border-right: none;">Three</li>
     <li style="border-bottom: none;">Four</li>
    <li style="border-bottom: none;">Five</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 30px;
}

ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.three li {
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: its really not clear what you want?

Comment: could you add an example of the expected result?

Comment: I added some expected result. Best seen in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want borders on the inside and none around the container, you may add a container with `overflow:hidden;` and use negative margins on the `<ul>` element to hide the unwanted borders :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wqhgx4mc/2/)**

This way, you don't have to target each element to add specific borders to it according to it's position in the container.

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.three li {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="three">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```